Convert multiple Shapes into ShapeRange and group them in Office Word (VSTO)
Current situation
This is my first time trying to develop add-in with VSTO. Currently I am working on the add-in development of VSTO Word, hoping to achieve the same function in Excel, Word, and Powerpoint.
The approximate content of this function is:

Add shapes
Group shapes
Copy shapes to memory and output into png file

The Excel add-in (with some function) has been successfully developed, and a Word version is currently being developed. However, I encountered a problem: I couldn't successfully use ShapeRange to include all Shapes. The code looks like this.
Code
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;
...
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace StampWordAddIn
{
    ...

    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void btnStamp_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create Stamp
            Word.Document activeDocument = ((Word.Document)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
            Word.Shape stampCircle = activeDocument.Shapes.AddShape((int)Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval, 30f, 30f, 80f, 80f);
            stampCircle.Name = "stamp1";
            Word.Shape stampDate = activeDocument.Shapes.AddLabel(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 30f, 48f, 80f, 40f);
            stampDate.Name = "stamp2";
            stampDate.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Date";

            //Group the shapes (where the error located)
            string[] name = { "stamp1", "stamp2"};
            Word.ShapeRange shapeRange = activeDocument.Shapes.Range(name);

            //Save shapes to PNG file
            shapeRange.GroupItems[shapeRange.Count].Duplicate();
            MessageBox.Show("d");
            System.Drawing.Image image = GetMetaImageFromClipboard();
            string filename = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            image.Save("c:\\temp\\" + filename + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            //Delete group shape
            shapeRange.Delete();

            //Load png with transparent background
            Word.Range stampRange = activeDocument.Application.Selection.Range;
            Word.Window stampWin = activeDocument.ActiveWindow;
            Word.Shape stampPic = activeDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\\temp\\" + filename + ".png", Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0f, 0f, 30f, 30f);
            int left = 0, top = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
            stampWin.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, stampRange);
            stampPic.Name = "stamp";
            stampPic.Left = left;
            stampPic.Top = top;
            stampPic.ZOrder(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringForward);

            //Securely delete png file
            WipeFile("c:\\temp\\" + filename + ".png", 10);
        }
    }

    ...

}

I've tried using activeDocument.Shapes.Range(name) and SelectAll() to select and group Shapes, but it doesn't work.
